# Adding pagination to an ASP.NET MVC Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application in which I have a list as a model:

```
<table class="table_data" border="1">
    <tr>
        @if(Model.Count > 0){
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Fonction")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Nom du client")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Date de réception")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Date de clôture")
        </th>
            <th></th>
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach(Planning.Models.Paire p in Model){
        <tr>
        <td>
                <label>@p._tag</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>@p._client</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label>@p._reception</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label>@p._cloture</label>
      
       </td>  
            <td>
                @{
                        List<Planning.Models.Impaire> liste = u.Get_Impaire_List();
                     Planning.Models.Impaire imp = liste.Find(x => x.id_paire == p.Id);

                    if (imp != null){
           @Html.ActionLink("voir plus de détails", "Details", new { id_paire = p.Id })}
                }
       </td>  
    </tr> 
    }
</table>
```

The Model is `List<Paire>`.

I'd like to display each 15 lines together in the same view. How can I add  pagination between pages at the same view?

Can I use Ajax to do that?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: You certainly can use AJAX to fetch paged data from the server.  Though if you're not addressing any performance issue and just want paging, there's no reason to turn one server call into many.  Tools like DataTables (https://datatables.net) will add paging/sorting/filtering to your table with a single line of code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
$('table.table_data').each(function () {
        var currentPage = 0;
        var numPerPage = 15;
        var $table = $(this);
        $table.bind('repaginate', function () {
            $table.find('tbody tr').hide().slice(currentPage * numPerPage, (currentPage + 1) * numPerPage).show();
        });
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        var numRows = $table.find('tbody tr').length;
        var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / numPerPage);
        var $pager = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
        for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
            $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
                newPage: page
            }, function (event) {
                currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
                $table.trigger('repaginate');
                $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }).appendTo($pager).addClass('clickable');
        }

        $pager.insertAfter($table).find('span.page-number:first').addClass('active');

    });
```

You need to add `<tbody>` tag, to split body's rows and head row:

```html
<table class="table_data" border="1">
    <tr>
        @if(Model.Count > 0){
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Fonction")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Nom du client")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Date de réception")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.Label("Date de clôture")
        </th>
            <th></th>
        }
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    @foreach(Planning.Models.Paire p in Model){
        <tr>
        <td>
                <label>@p._tag</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>@p._client</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label>@p._reception</label>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label>@p._cloture</label>

       </td>  
            <td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

And add CSS for pager:

```css
div.pager {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0;
}

div.pager span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.8em;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #216aaf;
    color: #fff;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

div.pager span.active {
    background: #e6f1fb;
    color:#216aaf;
}
```

Comment: sorry i still not understand how can i move to the next page, by which event? Do i have to add a button next and prev?

Comment: @Lamloumi no, this code aitomatically adds buttons with page numbers and adds click events to that buttons. Do not forget to add css that I've written.

Comment: @AndriyGubal from model I am getting data arranged in desc order, however by using your code pagination works but its not arranged in desc order. please help me in fixing this issue

Comment: how to limit the page number `span` , it's getting increases as data is increased.

Answer (score 3):

Try This
One of the easiest method

Controller

```cs
using PagedList;
public ActionResult Index(int ? pagePos)
{
        //return View(db.Items.ToList());// Change this as following
        int pageNumber = (pagePos ?? 1);
        return View(db.Items.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber, 30));
        //30 equels number of items per page
}
```

Index.cshtml

```cs
@*@model IEnumerable<ProjectDB.Models.Item>*@
@*Change These Also as following*@
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ProjectDB.Models.Item>
@using PagedList.Mvc


<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Code
    </th>
    
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
    </td>
  
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
}   
</table>

@*Pagination Code Starts*@

<div class="pageCount">
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
</div>
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagePos => Url.Action("Index", new { pagePos }))
```